# Why can I repeat the + in Python arbitrarily in a calculation?

Tags: python, syntax

Today I have started to learn Python. The first things I learned were values, expressions and (arithmetic) operators. So far, everything makes sense, except one thing that I don not get:

While

```
2+2
```

evaluates to `4` (which makes sense),

```
2+
```

results in a `SyntaxError` (which also makes sense). But what – from my point of view – does *not* make sense is the following line of code:

```
2+++2
```

This results in `4` as well, and I wonder why. If I can compare this to JavaScript (which I use on a day-to-day basis), this results in an error in JavaScript.

So, two questions:

1. Why does this not result in a syntax error?
2. How does this expression get evaluated? What happens to the additional `+` signs?

Comment: Considering 2-2=0 ; 2--2=4 ; 2---2=0 I would say the 2+++2 is evaluated as 2 + 2

Comment: But shouldn't `2---2` require parentheses? Somehow, this looks quite strange IMHO.

Comment: The Order of operation is from left to right so: 2-- evaluates to 2+ and 2+-2 evaluates to 2 - 2 = 0.

Comment: It's parsed perfectly in JavaScript if you add spaces so it doesn't look like an increment operator: `2 + + + + + + + + + + + + + + 2`. I'd be more surprised to hear of a programming language or scientific calculator where this *doesn't* work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Python has an [unary `+` operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#unary-arithmetic-and-bitwise-operations) - `+2` will evaluate to `2`. So, that expression is actually evaluated as:

```
2+(+(+2))
```

Which, of course, is `4`.

Comment: Ah, I see! Thanks 

Comment: Which you can "prove" by  `ast.dumps(ast.parse('2+++2'))` if you fancied.

Answer (score 3):

According to the official documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#additional-methods-on-integer-types),

```
+2 # refers to 2

2+++2# unary + has higher precedence than addition

2++2 # same logic

2+2
4
```